# concurrent UDP server using select() call

Tags: c, sockets, select, network-programming, udp

I am following [this](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#select) example. Only change that I want to make is that instead of having a TCP concurrent server, I want the server to be UDP server.

I was initially getting error message that listen() is not supported, which makes sense. There is no point of having listen() on UDP socket.

Now I am stuck at `accept: Operation not supported` error message. The line which is causing the error is -  `newfd = accept(listener,(struct sockaddr *)&remoteaddr,&addrlen);`

My question is- how do I do I/O multiplexing on UDP sockets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since UDP is NOT connection oriented, you can't do an accept.  You have to read from the bound UDP socket, which gives you a packet.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the IP:Port of the incoming packets. This information is available as part of recvfrom().